# What is the recommended --v log level for k8s control plane components in production cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to find a reasonable log level in which control plane component (e.g. kubelet) would print enough information helping debug when a problem happens, and also the log file size wouldn't be too large, causing any potential disk io problem.

K8s log level flag --v is not well documented,  the most helpful doc I can find is [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging) , it is about kubectl's --v falg, so I'm not sure if it's correct with kubelet, or apiserver, the description of log level 5 is also missing.

Is there any other docs? Or is there any best practice of --v setting?

Answer (score 4):

> `kubectl --v=5 - Trace level verbosity` is [documented here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-instrumentation/logging.md)

On a production cluster i will **recommend keeping default log level**, and only change to more verbose logs when needed to debug cluster level issues (and return the log verbosity back to default after any such troubleshooting is done)

> to change kublet verbosity you can append **`/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env`** file with --v=5 flag and restart kublet to read to required verbosity .